# Graded readers using traditional Chinese characters?

Tags: resource-request, reading, chinese, graded-readers

Graded readers are very useful for practising extensive reading. [Extensive reading has several benefits](http://www.teachingenglish.org.uk/article/extensive-reading-why-it-good-our-students%E2%80%A6-us), for example, getting a lot of comprehensible input.

I have found several series of graded readers that use simplified Chinese characters, such as Chinese Breeze and the series by the Foreign Languages Teaching and Research Press (FLTRP). However, I have not found any graded readers that use traditional Chinese characters. (I have found [basal readers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basal_reader) for Chinese/Taiwanese schoolchildren, but that is not the same thing.)

Can anybody suggest graded readers written in traditional Chinese characters?

Answer (score 3):

As it turns out, the graded readers from Mandarin Companion have been converted to traditional characters.

- [安末 / Emma](http://mandarincompanion.com/products/emma/) (300 unique characters);
- [卷发公司的案子 / Sherlock Holmes and the Case of the Curly Haired Company](http://mandarincompanion.com/products/sherlock-holmes-and-the-red-headed-league/) (300 unique characters);
- [盲人国](http://mandarincompanion.com/products/the-country-of-the-blind/) (300 unique characters);
- [猴爪 / http://mandarincompanion.com/products/the-monkeys-paw/](http://mandarincompanion.com/products/the-monkeys-paw/) (300 unique characters);
- [王子和穷孩子 / The Prince and the Pauper](http://mandarincompanion.com/products/the-prince-and-the-pauper/) (300 unique characters);
- [秘密花园 / The Secret Garden](http://mandarincompanion.com/products/the-secret-garden/) (300 unique characters);
- [六十年的梦 / The Sixty-Year Dream](http://mandarincompanion.com/products/the-sixty-year-dream/) (300 unique characters);
- [美好的前途（上） / Great Expectations: Part 1](http://mandarincompanion.com/products/great-expectations-part-1/) (450 unique characters);
- [美好的前途（下） / Great Expectations: Part 2](http://mandarincompanion.com/products/great-expectations-part-2/) (450 unique characters);
- [地心游记 / Journey to the Center of the Earth](http://mandarincompanion.com/products/journey-to-the-center-of-the-earth/) (450 unique characters).

Another set of graded readers is the [Happy Reader's Series](http://www.shop.panasiabooks.com/index.php?cPath=11_15) published by Pan Asia Publishing. It contains titles such as 猴小子穿鞋子 / Shoes for Monkey Young, 美麗的圖畫 / A Beautiful Picture and 我們看見恐龍了 / We Have Seen a Dinosaur! The books contain traditional Chinese characters, an English translation and pinyin  Unfortunately, these books are aimed at children, not adults.

Answer (score 0):

Try this series of book. You'd love them. [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B09DB1P4VW](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09DB1P4VW)

Comment: Hi. Could you please recheck the link? It does not seem to work. In addition, a good answer does not simply provide a link but describes the most important information. I this case, you should at least at the name of the publisher and the most important characteristics of the graded readers, especially their reading level.